# Users' can not access sites even with correct permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

We're running on SharePoint Online at our company and I can't seem to figure out why users are unable to access specific sites inside a site collection.

They have proper read permissions and are in the correct group, but are still getting access denied errors.  I removed all the unique permissions on the site and nothing should be preventing them from access this resource.  Even "Checking Permissions" on a users profile shows they should have access.  There are no webparts on the page with unique permissions as well.  They can only see a resource on this page when I added them to a full control owners group.

Any ideas?  I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... The "Shared Documents" library had versionion set to only allow "users who can edit items" to see draft items in the library.  The document was edited, thus creating major versions.

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions are correct, one possibility is the default page of the site might be checked-out or in draft state. That also result in Access Denied error.

Answer (score 0):

remove the user completely from the site collection and then add the user again.